# Boolean Equivalent For `System.Numerics.IBitwiseOperators` Interface

Tags: c#, .net-core, interface, boolean, system.numerics

Included in the `System.Numerics` library is the relatively new interface `IBitwiseOperators<TSelf, TOther, TResult>`. It contains functionality for bitwise manipulations on integers (e.g. AND, OR, XOR, and NOT).

However, booleans do not implement it. What is the equivalent of this interface for booleans?

I know this is kind of a newbie question, but I can't find the answer anywhere on the internet. I checked the Microsoft documentation, but didn't really know what to look for.

Any help please?

I am using this to create a generic function to assist in the creation of delegates which will be used on dynamically-typed values.

Effectively, one part of my code is this function:

```
T Not<T>(T Value) where T : ? => !Value;
```

Which is later assigned to a delegate:

```
Func<bool, bool> d = Not<bool>;
```

Which is later applied to a variable:

```
x = d(x);
```

Which function `d` will be set to is determined at runtime; the not operator is only one of the potential functions.

I use the interface as a type constraint so that the function doesn't throw a runtime error.

Comment: The answer is.... I don't think there is one. Remember `Boolean` is not a numeric/integral type on the .NET platform. (Other platforms have different semantics for their boolean types.)

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Richard I edited it in.

Comment: @Richard `Boolean` is an integral type, a 32-bit integer, check ECMA-335 Part I Section 8.2.2 and Part III Section 7.4 https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_5th_edition_december_2010.pdf

Comment: @Charlieface that is how they are stored. You need to consider the operations that numbers have but `Boolean` does not. Eg. addition and subtraction. (`Char` is also stored as a 16 bit value which the CPU can treat as a number, but you can't operate on numerically in .NET, except by converting to a numeric type and then converting back.)

Comment: @Richard Again not true. C# does indeed treat it that way, but as far as .NET Runtime is concerned, `char` is just a `short` and `bool` is an `int`. There is no conversion at all. See https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUAlBVTdwG4CGAJwJ8CAXgIByAB4SA3F27V+QgEZiCLMADtgbEfALp52bgF8cpoA for `char` there is no conversion being done, and in theory C# compiler could do the same for `bool`. The IL has no concept of `char` and `bool` once put on the stack, they are just `int`.

Comment: I know that at a machine (including a virtual CPU model like IL) won't distinguish them:  at that level the interpretation is down to which instructions are applied (eg. how one can see the bytes for a floating point). This question is abo8ut C#! Where they are different because the language (and BCL) semantics apply.